# How to sum Multilistbox Item?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

I have a Multilistbox which has 3 column. 1st column is Serial No. 2nd column is particulars and 3rd column is Amount $. Amount column has two given item price. I wanted to sum these item price in the given entry. My code has 2 class, In my first class I create Multilistbox and second class I called It. I'm also attached my code and a picture about my designed.

[Heare is my designed picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIwrS.png)

Heare is My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MultiListbox(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky="nsew")
        self.select_index = None
        i = 2
        for num, (l, w) in enumerate(lists):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(num, weight=w, uniform='fred')
            i += num
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.lists = []

        for num, (l, w) in enumerate(lists):
            frame = Frame(self, borderwidth=0)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            frame.grid(row=1, column=num, sticky="nsew")
            Label(frame, text=l, font=("Vrinda (Body CS)", 11), borderwidth=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor="center", justify="center").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            lb = Listbox(frame, font=("Vrinda (Body CS)", 9), height=5, borderwidth=1, selectborderwidth=1, exportselection=FALSE)
            lb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.lists.append(lb)
            lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: 'break')
            lb.bind('<B2-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._b2motion(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('&lt;Button-4>', lambda e, s=self: s._scroll(SCROLL, 1, PAGES))
            lb.bind('&lt;Button-5>', lambda e, s=self: s._scroll(SCROLL, -1, PAGES))
            lb.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)

        sb_y = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command=self._yscroll)
        sb_y.grid(row=1, rowspan=2, column=i, sticky="nsew")
        self.lists[0]['yscrollcommand'] = sb_y.set

        ent_total = Entry(self, width=0, justify="center")
        ent_total.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nesw")
        ent_total.insert(0, "Total")
        ent_sum_value = Entry(self, width=0)
        ent_sum_value.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nesw")

        sb_x = Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self._xscroll)
        sb_x.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=i, sticky="ew")
        self.lists[0]['xscrollcommand'] = sb_x.set

    def _select(self, y):
        row = self.lists[0].nearest(y)
        self.selection_clear(0, END)
        self.selection_set(row)
        return 'break'

    def _button2(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_mark(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _b2motion(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_dragto(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _yscroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.yview(*args)

    def _xscroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.xview(*args)

    def curselection(self):
        return self.lists[0].curselection()

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.delete(first, last)

    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for l in self.lists:
            result.append(l.get(first,last))
        if last: return list(map(*[None] + result))
        return result

    def index(self, index):
        self.lists[0].index(index)

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        for e in elements:
            i = 0
            for l in self.lists:
                l.insert(index, e[i])
                i = i + 1

    def size(self):
        return self.lists[0].size()

    def see(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.see(index)

    def selection_anchor(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_anchor(index)

    def selection_clear(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_clear(first, last)

    def selection_includes(self, index):
        return self.lists[0].selection_includes(index)

    def selection_set(self, first, last=None):
        self.select_index =[first]
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_set(first, last)

    def OnMouseWheel(self, event):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.yview("scroll", event.delta,"units")
        # this prevents default bindings from firing, which
        # would end up scrolling the widget twice
        return "break"


class FormAddProduct:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = master
        self.frame.configure(padx=5)
        for i in range(0, 1):
            self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure (1, weight = 1)
        self._init_widgets()

    def _init_widgets(self):
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.frame, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        for i in range(0, 1):
            self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(0, 1):
            self.frame1.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.mlb = MultiListbox(self.frame1,(
            ('SL.', 1), ('Particulars', 3), ('Amount $', 1)))
        self.mlb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        a1 = tup = (1, "Apple", 10)
        a2 = tup = (2, "Orange", 25)
        self.mlb.insert(END, a1)
        self.mlb.insert(END, a2)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=5)

def main():
    app = tk.Tk()
    FormAddProduct(app)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First associate a `StringVar` to `ent_sum_value`:

```
    self.sum_value = StringVar(value=0)
    ent_sum_value = Entry(self, width=0, textvariable=self.sum_value)
```

Then create a function in `MultiListbox` class:

```
def sum_values(self):
    total = sum(self.lists[-1].get(0, END))
    self.sum_value.set(total) # update ent_sum_value via self.sum_value StringVar
```

Call the above function wherever required, like in `insert(...)` function:

```
def insert(self, index, *elements):
    for e in elements:
        i = 0
        for l in self.lists:
            l.insert(index, e[i])
            i = i + 1
    self.sum_values()
```